# Blank response when i want to display postmeta Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-api

in there i want to display my data. when i try to display my data without postmeta its work but when i try to improve with postmeta i get blank response

```html
$command = $_GET['command'];
switch ($command) {
    case 'list_product':

        $loop = new WP_Query( 
                array(
                        'post_type'    => 'product'
                        // 'showposts'    => 4,
                        // 'meta_key'     => '_sale_price', 
                        // 'meta_value'   => '0', 
                        // 'meta_compare' => '>=',
                    )
                ); 
if($loop->have_posts()) :

    $data = array( "api_status" => 1, "api_message" => "success");
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

           $data[] = array("id" => get_the_ID(),
          "post_name" => get_the_title(),
          "post_meta" => get_post_meta(get_the_ID());

    endwhile;


    echo  json_encode($data);
break;
}
```

have someone help me what a improvement i need in my code, so my code can work like what i need ?

Answer (score 0):

Put the `$data = ...` *before* your `if` and add a `results` key with an empty array value to it. Put your `echo` after your `endif`.

In your `while`, add the results to that key using `$data['results'][] = ...`

---

**Edit:** spell it out a bit. If your results are empty then something else is wrong.

```
switch ($_GET['command']) {
    case 'list_product':

        $loop = new WP_Query( 
            array(
                'post_type'    => 'product',
                // 'showposts'    => 4,
                // 'meta_key'     => '_sale_price', 
                // 'meta_value'   => '0', 
                // 'meta_compare' => '>=',
            )
        );
        $data = array(
            'api_status' => 1,
            'api_message' => 'success',
            'results' => array(),
        );
        while ($loop->have_posts()) {
            $loop->the_post();
            $data['results'][] = array(
                'id' => get_the_ID(),
                'post_name' => get_the_title(),
                'post_meta' => get_post_meta(get_the_ID()),
            );
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$command = $_GET['command'];
switch ($command) {
    case 'list_product':

        $loop = new WP_Query(
            array(
                'post_type'    => 'product'
// 'showposts'    => 4,
// 'meta_key'     => '_sale_price',
// 'meta_value'   => '0',
// 'meta_compare' => '>=',
            )
        );

        if($loop->have_posts()) {

            $data = array( "api_status" => 1, "api_message" => "success");
            while( $loop->have_posts() ) {
                $loop->the_post();
                $data[] =   array(
                    "id" => get_the_ID(),
                    "post_name" => get_the_title(),
                    "post_meta" => get_post_meta(get_the_ID())
                );
            }

            /**
            $data[] =   array(
                "id" => get_the_ID(),
                "post_name" => get_the_title(),
                "post_meta" => get_post_meta(get_the_ID())
            );
             */

        }

        echo  json_encode($data);
        break;
}
```

Comment: Undefined index when no results.

Comment: I don't know about wordpress but I did see a missing "endif" in his statement. Due to my low point I can't add comment directly to question. OP must understand how to enable error debugging in first place

Comment: I have updated my answer.. I don't really know what to expect from those custom defined wordpress methods so $data[] could go inside or outside while clause. I just tried to fix syntax

Comment: `$data[]` could not go outside `while`. Initial `$data = ` must be outside the `if` scope.

Answer (score -1):

Please try with below code:

```
$loop = new WP_Query(
   array(
       'post_type'    => 'post'
   )
);

$data = array( "api_status" => 1, "api_message" => "success");
if($loop->have_posts()) {
 while( $loop->have_posts() ) {
     $loop->the_post();
     $data[] =   array(
         "id" => get_the_ID(),
         "post_name" => get_the_title(),
         "post_meta" => get_post_meta(get_the_ID())
     );
 }
}
echo  json_encode($data);
```